# How to write timestamp to thumbnail filename in ffmpeg keyframe extraction

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, command-prompt

I am extracting thumbnails from a video at custom intervals. Is there any way to write the time stamp, from which the thumbnail is extracted, to the thumbnail file name?

For example if I am extracting thumbnails in 5 sec intervals I want to get the key frames as  Thumb_00_00_05.jpg, Thumb_00_00_10.jpg and so on. My purpose is to set a navigation rule to the time stamp on clicking this thumbnail

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Sorry. Just edited. I was trying to do that through command line interface.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/433871/ffmpeg-extract-frames-and-get-their-exact-timestamps

Comment: Rather, see: http://superuser.com/questions/841872/how-do-i-extract-the-timestamps-associated-with-frames-ffmpeg-extracts-from-a-vi